# Android Studio debugging on emulator: Client not ready yet

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, android-emulator

I am currently unable to debug on the emulator due the following:

> Client not ready yet.

When I first started using the emulator with this app I was able to print out messages. However now nothing works. I don't see any logs and no breaks points are hit.

I just get the above message. Has anyone else experienced a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you use android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger(), try to remove it, because studio works well without above codes unlike eclipse.

Comment: I am not calling android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger() in my app.

Comment: Then try to kill the debug attempt (look for a red square) and start the emulator from the AVD manager, then wait for it to get to the home screen before trying to debug your app. Other way: use external tools like www.genymotion.com

Comment: I have tried to kill the debug attempt and start the emulator from the AVD manager but no luck. I will take a look at genymotion. Thanks.